# Blogger thumbnails for external images

Tags: html, image, metadata, blogger

The website in quetion is: http://twisted-perfectionism.blogspot.com/

I've been trying to set up a Popular Posts (via Blogger) or Recommended Posts (via Shareaholic) Widget, but thumbnails do not appear.

The problem is the fact that the images are not hosted by blogger. I post them as:

```
<img src="..">
```

I know that if I upload the photos to blogger the issue would be fixed. But I don't want to, I want them to be hosted somewhere else.

I've tried replacing

```
data:post.thumbnail with data:blog.postImageUrl
```

but with no success.

I even tried adding this to the header:

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' name='shareaholic:image'/>
```

but the result is the same. No thumbnails. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue fixed itself after a couple of days.
I suppose it takes some time for Shareaholic to index the website and provide the thumbnails